# Trying to import data from JSON file, and displaying in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, json

Here's the script I'm using :

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("myQuiz", []);

    app.controller('QuizController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce){

        $scope.score = 0;
        $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
        $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentage = 0;

        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){

            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;

        });

    }])
})
```

After this, I'm trying to display the 'total questions' on my HTML using `{{totalQuestions}}` but instead of showing the number of questions, it just displays `{{totalQuestions}}` as it is.

Comment: You probably get an **error in console**, can you provide it, please?

Comment: I am using the sublime text editor. When I run my html file on the browser, it just displays {{totalQuestions}} as it is. No error.

Comment: Which browser you are using if chrome you might get an error to read file directly, otherwise share some more code with us or create a [http://plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) to replicate the problem

Comment: The error is on the console of your **browser**, not on your editor...

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=myQuiz&p1=Error%3A%…(file%3A%2F%2F%2FF%3A%2FQuizApp%2FCh01%2F01_01%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:41
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:40)
    at eb (angular.min.js:45)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at Mc (angular.min.js:21)
    at pe (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:329
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:37)

Comment: This was the error I found on the console. Unable to figure out at all. :|

Comment: @Pratyush Arya .use F12 and click on console.you can see there

Comment: @Shiva, I found the error, but unable to find a way around it.

Comment: your error means that you're importing a module in a NOT correct way ..espaccialy it looks MyQuiz module is not correct

Comment: have you imported it in your index.html?

Comment: <html ng-app="myQuiz">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="myQuiz" ng-controller = 'QuizController'> 
   <h1>Test Your Knowledge: <span>Saturn</span></h1>
   <div class="progress">

Comment: i guess i have imported it to the index.html. have i?

Answer (score 0):

You have this in code:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("myQuiz", []);
    // ..
})
```

But this will never actually execute the function, so your module won't be defined.

Just add the `()` at the end:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("myQuiz", []);
    // ..
}())
```

Comment: did that. still the same.

Comment: You of course also have to include the script in your index.html: `<head><script src="path/to/the/script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `<div id="myQuiz">` to something else it can not be same as `ng-app="myQuiz"` and define your scope variable inside `<div id="myQuizId" ng-controller = 'QuizController'> {{hereYourVariable}} </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add these things in your index.html file :

1. ng-app = "myQuiz",
2. ng-controller="QuizController" if required,
3. add reference to your  angular js cdn or its script file
4. then below angular cdn/script reference  add your script file reference.